# Unable to remove old interpreters from Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, jetbrains-ide

When I go to **Preferences | Python Interpreter | Show All ...** (as described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205819079-How-to-remove-old-virtualenv)) and try to remove an old interpreter, it seems to be successfully removed.

If I close and reopen ***only*** the **Project Interpreters** popup window it seems to have saved my changes, but when I close and reopen the **Preferences** window the interpreters are still there.

This happens regardless of whether I access the preferences window from an open project or not, so it shouldn't be a project-specific issue.

---

The interpreters I'm trying to remove are for old projects that don't exist anymore (as in the path to the project including the python binary has been deleted).

How can I remove these unused interpreters?

Bonus: what should I do in the future when I delete a project to ensure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Correct Answer

Looking at the logs, there was an error when trying to remove that said `Configuration.PythonSdkDetailsDialog - Please specify a different SDK name`

It turns out that I had a duplicate interpreter elsewhere in the interpreter list. Removing the duplicate (normally, using the minus button) and reopening the preferences window did the trick.

---

## Old Answer

Here's what I ended up doing:

Using [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html?_ga=2.140681778.1403549566.1588887906-1009011667.1588628138#), I found my configuration directory. I that directory, there was a file at `options/jdk.table.xml` which contained a list of interpreters.

Manually deleting entries here did the trick.

This still feels wrong to me, though, so I welcome a better solution.